# Download zipped files from ftp via RCurl

Tags: r

I had problems to download zipped files from a ftp server. But now I have solved the problem and because I haven't found any solution to my problem here, I'm sharing my approach. 
First I tried it with

```
 download.file()
```

But there was the problem that my password was ending with an "@". That's why the solution with submittign user and password within the URL wasn't working. The double @ was apparently confusing R.

```
url <- ftp://user:password@@url
```

You'll find the solution below. 
Maybe someone has some improvements.

Maybe for someone it's usefull, 
Florian

Comment: It's great that you solved your problem and it's ok to ask and immediately answer your own Q, but this is absolutely not how this site works. Edit your question and remove your solution, and then place it in an **answer** below. Please read the help section for SO carefully before asking more questions.

Comment: @joran: Done! Thanks for your hint. Wasn't aware of how to answer my own question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
library(RCurl)

url<- "ftp://adress/"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd="USER:PASSWORD", ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, dirlistonly = TRUE) #reading filenames from ftp-server
destnames <- filenames <-  strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]] # destfiles = origin file names
con <-  getCurlHandle( ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, userpwd="USER:PASSWORD")
mapply(function(x,y) writeBin(getBinaryURL(x, curl = con, dirlistonly = FALSE), y), x = filenames, y = paste("C:\\temp\\",destnames, sep = "")) #writing all zipped files in one directory
```

Hopefully for anybody it's usefull!
Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 2):

If you have no particular reason to stay with Rcurl, you can use this bash-based method:

```
   URL <- "ftp.server.ca"
   USR <- "aUserName"
   MDP <- "myPassword"
   OUT <- "output.file"
   cmd <- paste("wget -m --ftp-user=",USR," --ftp-password=",MDP, " ftp://", URL," -O ", OUT, sep="")
   system(cmd)
```